# grails tomcat plugin deploying to liferay?

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, liferay

Is there a way to deploy a grails application with `grails deploy` to liferay, instead of tomcat? Tomcat 6 comes with the `manager` and `host manager` app, which let you do a remote deployment, but Liferay is missing these applications.

[This grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/tomcat) seems to require the manager app running, but if I copy the folders from a vanilla tomcat instance to liferay, I get

`java.lang.SecurityException: Servlet of class org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet is privileged and cannot be loaded by this web application`

when I try to connect to `manager/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard manager deployment on Tomcat also has a context definition (which it appears that you're missing) that declares the context as 'privileged' and therefore able to *do privileged stuff*. The problem you're going to have is that you do not deploy Liferay plugins (including portlets) to Tomcat, you need to deploy to a location watched by Liferay and let Liferay do the deployment.

In my opinion you'll need to use `grails war` rather than deploy, and copy the WAR file to the *Liferay*/deploy directory

Comment: My real end is to have Jenkins/Hudson use the `grails -Dgrails.env=blah deploy` target to deploy to multiple different environments. Also, context.xml existed in the host-manager and manager configurations, and priveleged was set to true.

Comment: I just blogged about Continuous Integration with Liferay yesterday :) radio.javaranch.com/davo

Comment: and I realise that the blog is more about the ant tasks using the Liferay SDK, but at the end of the day provided you can build a WAR and get it into the liferay/deploy directory it is all the same from there.

Comment: I wound up making a post-build task of an scp command to the different environments.